# Initialize linkedlist in another method, null pointer exception

Tags: java

I have a method to initialize a linkedList and another one to run some recursive function over that list. However, in this similified example, I get an error trying to add a vertex to the linkedlist.

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

  public class Bla<T>{

    private LinkedList<T> resultList; 

    public LinkedList<T> experiment(T vertex){
       LinkedList<T> resultList = new LinkedList<T>();
       return experimentRecursive(vertex);
    }

    public LinkedList<T> experimentRecursive(T vertex){
       resultList.add(vertex);  
       return resultList;
    }

   public static void main (String args[]){

     Bla <String> hello= new Bla<String>();
     System.out.println(hello.experiment("A"));

    }
  }
```

Comment: And the error is? How about reading it, and posting its stack trace?

Comment: your `private LinkedList<T> resultList;` was never initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing local linked list in method, not member of class. `resultList` remains null even after method call because it was never initialized. Change the code to following...

```
 private LinkedList<T> resultList; 

 public LinkedList<T> experiment(T vertex){
    resultList = new LinkedList<T>();
    return experimentRecursive(vertex);
 }
```

P.S. : Please refer @JB's comment for better design.

Comment: +1. Note that having a public method initialize a member field, and another public method assuming the field is initialized is bad design. The field should be initialized by the constructor.

Comment: Yes I agree :) , but solution should not change OP's code if possible, so that is why initialized linkedlist in method.

Answer (score 1):

doing

```
public LinkedList<T> experiment(T vertex){
   LinkedList<T> resultList = new LinkedList<T>();
   return experimentRecursive(vertex);
}
```

you are not initializing the instance field. Instead do

```
public LinkedList<T> experiment(T vertex){
    resultList = new LinkedList<T>();
    return experimentRecursive(vertex);
}
```

or for a better readability

```
this.resultList = new LinkedList<T>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Mis-referencing the local variable, instead of the field.

Your design needs to be clear about whether it's just a *list* that gets changed by passed around, or whether the *class instance* wraps the list & gets changed.

Calling `new Bla<String>().experiment("A")` could just modify & return a local list, but you appear to be trying to put "Builder" semantics on top of this.